# Music was better closer to the 80's - Riddle

Tags: riddle, music

Did we do something wrong?

Are we to blame for modern song?

Beliebers rule, but the Beatles I long.

$\\$

For teenagers, I fear

#yolo is what they hear

Good music is nowhere near.

$\\$

Do we need to go way way back?

Get music pure and not so black?

Aha I know exactly which track!

Comment: What does "pure and not so black" mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer appears to be:

> [Pachelbel's Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachelbel's_Canon)

Because:

> Taking an acrostic of the riddle provides the first eight notes of the song.

Comment: how did you search the notes?

Comment: @manshu - literally just googled "D A B F# G D G A"

Comment: @manshu some people know them by sight

Comment: Interestingly, Green Day's song Basket Case has the same chord structure.